# How can I upgrade my GETH?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, upgrading

I have an application which is talking to my Smart Contract through GETH RPC.

In order to do so, I need to run my own node and sync it with mainnet.

The problem start when I need to upgrade my GETH. During the upgrade, I will need to bring down GETH. And when GETH is downed (even for 1 min), it will take hell lots of time to get back in sync.

I don't know how long my GETH can run without an upgrade. Any best practice?

Comment: What kind of machine are you using? Do you have an SSD? It sounds like this may simply be a hardware issue.

Comment: 16GB Intel 17 with GTX1060 6GB and 500GB SSD, 500mbps internet connection. I don't think I have any hardware issue.

Comment: what is you current version and what is the version you are going to upgrade `geth` to ?

Answer (score 2):

For something not very critical we have two nodes, one as master and second as backup.

We upgrade the backup first, check everything is ok and then set it as master. Let the old master running the old version until we are confident with the new version.